# How to avoid modifying Firebase Firestore data when working on new version of a app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed an app (my first app) that's currently on app- and playstore. I'm using Firebase/Firestore as a back-end/database. I'm about to start to work on the next version of the app, which will require me to modify my database for testing and such. However, I currently have about 100 regular users on the app and I wouldn't want them to experience any weird data changes on their app while I'm developing.

I'm simply not sure about the way it's done when you further develop an existing app. I was thinking of creating new collections in Firestore simply for testing and hook my app with them but I don't know if that's the best way to go.

How do I work on a new version of an app without my users seeing any changes in their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data model is (very) simple you could create some specific, temporary, collections as you describe, but this is quite an error-prone approach (risk of modifying existing data, wrong or missing security rules, etc..) and is not  recommended.

One standard approach is simply to create another Firebase project which is totally isolated from the production project. You will need to change the Firebase configuration in your Flutter app. If you need existing production data in your test Firebase project you could use the [export/import mechanism](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#managing_export_and_import_operations).

Comment: My data model is simple yes but in the long run, the second method you describe would be more beneficiary and re-useable for additional future versions.

Would you recommend that the new testing Firebase project be identical to the production one and before deploying, you would configure the app to use the production database?

Comment: "Would you recommend that the new testing Firebase project be identical to the production one and before deploying, you would configure the app to use the production database?" => Yes, exactly.